# Dynamic Oracle Statement

Tags: oracle

Why do I always get the below Error?

```
Fehlerbericht: ORA-00933: SQL-Befehl wurde nicht korrekt beendet
ORA-06512: in Zeile 13
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

My code:

```
DECLARE
  match_count INTEGER;
  v_owner VARCHAR2(255) :='XXX';
  v_data_type VARCHAR2(255) :='CHAR';
  sqlstr varchar(255) := '';

BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_cols where owner=v_owner and data_type = v_data_type and column_name = 'TEST') LOOP
  match_count:=0;

  if length(t.table_name) > 0 then
    sqlstr := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || t.table_name || ' WHERE TEST<> ''000''';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr into match_count;
  end if;

    IF match_count > 0 THEN
        execute immediate 'insert into search_db_results values (' || '''' || t.table_name || '''' || ',' || '''' || match_count || '''' || ')';

    END IF;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Try adding a ; to your dynamic SQL statements.

Comment: And there is no reason why you should use dynamic SQL for that insert statement. A normal insert would be better (and remove all the ugly nested quotes and string concatenation)

Comment: which sql statement triggers the error?

Comment: Print out the sql-statement before execution, maybe in t.table_name there is some garbage? Semicolon should not be required for the select-statement...

Comment: In addition to what @pbhd commented, [Here is an example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b933b/1)

Comment: @pbhd Thank you there was some garbage in the Tabel-Names.

Comment: the last statement does not have to be dynamic. just execute `insert into search_db_results values (t.table_name , match_count);`